# Python: How to close Chrome Notification using send_keys?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

So I'm trying to automatically join a Google Meet conference. Everything works fine, till there are coming up two Google Notifications. The first one is, if I wanna see the notification and the second one is, if Google is allowed to use mic and vidcamera. So I tried to get there out with basically just simulating escape but it doesnt work. So here is what I got so far(I know about the displacement after line 5):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Enrique\Desktop\J\chromedriver")
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmeet.google.com%2Fhws-mxht-wnk&sacu=1&hl=de&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys('Mail')
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
    time.sleep(6)
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('Password')
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
    time.sleep(6)
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span").click() #jetzt teilnehmen
```

Comment: `Selenium` has access only to elements in HTML but notyfications are not part of HTML (but part of browser's GUI). You may have to try to use `options` in `Chrome()` to block notifications.

Comment: Alright thank you, I will look for solutions in that direction.